# Use of 'make' and 'enable' in supplication

Tags: clauses

I came across a thought while writing a religious text. A structure entangled me a little. Which of the following sounds natural?

> 1. Lord enable us to die a believer!
> 2. Lord make us die a believer!

I think first one is better since one won't seek ability to die. But rather Lord makes us die. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use *let* here.  *Let* is commonly used in English as a polite form of a command and also used in blessings/requests for blessings.

> Lord let us die a believer!

Answer (score 0):

"enable" carries the meaning that currently you cannot be a believer, unless God actually changes something about it;

"make" also carries the meaning of doing it by force; but God will not force you to be believer;

I would say:

> Lord, help us die believers!